# Should I use hybrid app for large app?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a 3+ years experience in web development and developed few small app in Ionic and Phonegap. But now I jitter to develop a large app in hybrid app instead of native.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should consider many aspects when developing Hybrid Application:

**1. Performance**
Hybrid app suffer in performance, though a framework like Xamarin have close to native performance, we still get an app that not 'so fast' when we have a little low performance here and there.

**2. UI**
If you want to create an awesome user experience, the native app approach would be better. A hybrid app can never match the level of creative user experience that you get in a native app. However, this doesn’t mean that the user experience of a hybrid app is bad. A good front-end developer in hybrid app can get close to a native experience, but it’s a far stretch.

**2. Maintainability**
  Hybrid framework proudly tell us that we only need to maintain one project for Android, IOS, and other. But behind the curtain, we can't developing happily without touching the native aspect of app ecosystem. For example, UI in Android and IOS have a different look and feel and also have a different handling. So, instead maintaining one project, we end up maintaining `one project + the other app ecosystem`. This not really good for the long run.

Read more at:

- [Hybrid vs Native Mobile App. Decide in 5 minutes!](http://julyrapid.com/hybrid-vs-native-mobile-app-decide-5-minutes/)
- [Lessons Learned From 5 Year of PhoneGap/Cordova Development](http://www.agingcoder.com/programming/2015/02/21/lessons-learned-from-5-years-of-phonegapcordova-development/)
- [Why I don't Recommend Xamarin For Mobile Development](http://www.whitneyland.com/2013/05/why-i-dont-recommend-xamarin-for-mobile-development.html)

Answer (score 3):

Cross platform development can be a time saving opportunity if you already master either web development (apache cordova) or C# (unity, xamarin).

It could be too long to learn java, xml, swift, sqlite and IDEs such as xCode and Android Studio.

Most functionalities can be handled by cross platform solutions and most APIs are supported.

The size of the app isn't important in order to make a decision. Functionalities implied are.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what kind of "Large App" you are after, but in general perspective you can use [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/) for building native apps with single codebase and cross platform support.

Answer (score 1):

Do one thing, making hybrid app don't take longer time. so make hybrid app and make it live till den and start working for native.
it's ok you can use hybrid app but as you know there are limitations in hybrid app.
if you want your app fully functional in your way you should go for native , otherwise hybrid is fine.

Answer (score 1):

To add up to all the above points, cordova official documentation suggests cordova applications to be a single page application for better performance. So if you gotta develop a larger app, you need to check whether you can manage it as a SPA.

You can checkout the [official documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/next/) to decide which approach to take based on your requirement.